# Disable backspace in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am working in a WPF application, using C#.net
I want to know, is there any way to disable <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button on a particular xaml page.
I want to prevent user from using the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button on this particular xaml page. Even if the user presses the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button, no effect should take place.

Thanks

Answer (score 31):

If you want to prevent backspace going back up the navigation history in a WPF Frame, including special "Back" hardware buttons, use:

```cs
NavigationCommands.BrowseBack.InputGestures.Clear();
NavigationCommands.BrowseForward.InputGestures.Clear();
```

Comment: Where does this go in the code? In App.xaml.cs or something?

Comment: Ok figured it out - put this in the `NavigationWindow` constructor.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to catch the onKeyDown event and set handled to true for backspace.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Back)
    {
         e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If he meant navigation, then the situation might be a bit more complex, as you probably have to handle Alt+Left and some mouse buttons as well.

Comment: This should actually handle the PreviewKeyDown event, otherwise if another control has focus (like TextBox), the key press won't get intercepted.  Since he hasn't said why he wants to disable the backspace key, maybe he wants to support it in entry controls.

Comment: Thanks. In XBAP, handling `KeyDown` (*not* `PreviewKeyDown`) did the trick, The other solution looks much cleaner (`NavigationCommands...InputGestures.Clear()`) - but did not work for me in XBAP.

Comment: I preferred this approach because I did not want to disable all keyboard shortcut (I still want to use ALT-Left etc just not the Backspace).  For me using a WPF NavigationWindow, overriding the `OnKeyDown` method did not work but overriding the `OnPreviewKeyDown` did work.

Answer (score 1):

So I preferred the [approach by sipwiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700104/340045) because I did not want to disable all keyboard shortcut (I still want to use ALT-Left etc just not the Backspace).

For me using a WPF NavigationWindow, overriding the `OnKeyDown` method did not work at all, the window still navigated back when I pressed the Backspace key.  Overriding the `OnPreviewKeyDown` did seem to work to start with but then I ran into problems when I needed the Backspace key to work with textboxes.

So I took what I learned from the [approach by Ed Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7304280/340045) and I added the following code to my NavigationWindow constructor:

```
KeyGesture backKeyGesture = null;
foreach(var gesture in NavigationCommands.BrowseBack.InputGestures)
{
    KeyGesture keyGesture = gesture as KeyGesture;
    if((keyGesture != null) &&
       (keyGesture.Key == Key.Back) &&
       (keyGesture.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None))
    {
        backKeyGesture = keyGesture;
    }
}

if (backKeyGesture != null)
{
    NavigationCommands.BrowseBack.InputGestures.Remove(backKeyGesture);
}
```