# How to disable Alt + arrow key frame navigation?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I started an WPF application in a mvvm way. The main window contains a frame-control for navigating through differnt pages. For this I use a simple NavigationService for now:

```cs
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{

   private Frame _mainFrame;


    #region INavigationService Member

    public event NavigatingCancelEventHandler Navigating;

    public void NavigateTo(Uri uri)
    {
        if(EnsureMainFrame())
        {
            _mainFrame.Navigate(uri);
        }
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        if(EnsureMainFrame() && _mainFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            _mainFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private bool EnsureMainFrame()
    {
        if(_mainFrame != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var mainWindow = (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow);
        if(mainWindow != null)
        {
            _mainFrame = mainWindow.NavigationFrame;
            if(_mainFrame != null)
            {
                // Could be null if the app runs inside a design tool
                _mainFrame.Navigating += (s, e) =>
                                             {
                                                 if (Navigating != null)
                                                 {
                                                     Navigating(s, e);
                                                 }
                                             };
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

On Page1 a button press forces the navigation to Page2 using th NavigationService.
On Page2 there is a TextBox. If the TextBox is focused i can use ALT + left arrow key to navigate back to Page1. How can I disable this behavior?

I tried setting KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None" in the frame-control and also in the TextBox-Control without success.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367876/how-disable-navigation-shortcuts-in-frame-c-sharp-wpf/8239977#8239977

Answer (score 4):

Add the following event handler to the textbox to disable the alt + left navigation:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt)) 
        && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left)))
    {
         e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBox ... KeyDown="textBox1_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

**EDIT:** changed to PreviewKeyDown in order to capture arrow key events

Comment: He Tom, thank you. This seems to be reasonable working solution, but it feels to be a kind of brute force approach. I would have to implement this event handler for every control, or at least on every view in code behind. Maybe there is a more elegant solution in a "global" way? Couldn't it be handled within the frame control or the navigation service?

Comment: Try setting these properties as well: KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None"
KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="None"
KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"  From what I can find for forums, they seem to be connected.

Comment: And yes my answer is the brute force approach :)

Comment: I did try KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="None" and KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" as well, without success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8239977/1449777  - Have you tried this solution? Removing the last frame?

Comment: He Tom, thanks for your devotion. I came over this posting, but I need the BackStack for a breadcrumb bar implementation.

Comment: Have you tried the Attached behavior approach for that question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11037082/1449777

Comment: Yes. But it is not an option to remove the BackStack entries, because I do breadcrumb back navigation based on the back stack.

Comment: I stand by my original answer then.

Answer (score 0):

For going forward I used the key alt + right arrow for backward I used alt + left arrow.  To disable these short keys while using webview2 we can use this code.

```
Webview2 edge = new Webview2();

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        edge.KeyDown += EdgeWebBrowser_KeyDown;
    }

private void EdgeWebBrowser_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Menu) < 0)) || ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.Menu) < 0)) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.F5) || ((e.KeyCode == Keys.R) && (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) < 0)))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
    }
```